# Why does this simple python function only work once

Tags: python, function, counter

I want to create a simple counter so i created this function:

```
count = 0

def add(count):
    count += 1
    print(count)
```

and if re-called the count goes up to 1 but if I recall it again it stays at 1.
I also tried to output the count variable outside of the function after recalling it but that led to a constant output of 0

Comment: Change your function to `return count` instead of printing it,  call your function like this: `count=add(count)`, then `print (count)` after the call to `add()`. `count` inside the function is a different variable that is local to the function.

Comment: So I could also just declare `count` as being a global variable right?

Comment: You could, but don't.

Comment: It is technically possible to declare the variable inside the function as global (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function) but it is best to avoid that as it can lead to confusion. It is better practice to have the function simply return a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `count` variable in your function has a different scope to the `count` variable in the rest of your script. Modifying the former does not affect the latter.

You would need to do something like:

```
def add(count):
    count += 1
    print(count)
    return count

count = 0
count = add(count)
count = add(count)
```